# Dyanamic Parameters in SSRS Expression is Possible?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with a parameter. The parameter value can be passed from my Application. If the parameter is not passed from UI, it is considered as NULL. 
I am using IndexOf() on that parameter. Since it is null i am getting error.
I want to set parameter as some value if it is NULL. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can try: `IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!YourParam.Value),"Your Default Value When Null", "Your Value when not null")`. If you need further help include the expression you are using on the parameter.

Comment: I am using this expression in Parameter Expression. But still facing the issue =IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!DataColumn.Value),"12345",Parameters!DataColumn.Value)

Comment: Let me understand... where are you using that expression? You can't assign a parameter to its own value, i.e you can't assign parameter A to parameters!A.Value. The simplest solution to your problem is set a Default Value for your parameter under Report Parameter Properties / Default Value tab.

Comment: after adding expression for a parameter, if i pass null, i can get the correct value in profiler.. check datacolumn.But still getting error in Report                                    exec spRptPointsSummary_AccessLevel @CasinoId=NULL,@StartDt='2015-11-17 00:00:00',@EndDt='2016-11-18 00:00:00',@BucketGroupId=NULL,@DataColumn=N'1,2,3,4,5',@EmpId=25

Comment: What's the exact error?